# To show a subset, which is union of open sets, is proper in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was solving exercises from the book [Real Analysis by Carothers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521497566). I am having trouble in solving a part of Problem 58 of Exercise of chapter 4 on page 59. I have managed to solve the other parts of the problem but can not solve one part. Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Here is the problem.

> Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ and define interval $I_n$ for all $n$ which is $I_n=(r_n-2^{-n},r_n+2^{-n})$ and let $U=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ Prove that $U$ is proper,[open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set),[dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) subset of $\mathbb R$ and its complement is [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) in $\mathbb R$

Now I have proved all the parts except for showing $U$ is proper. I am completely stuck here. I can not find a way to show $U$ is proper. It seems to me that it should not be very difficult but perhaps I am missing something very trivial.

I apologise for not showing a good effort from my end but I am really stuck here. I am sorry.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the sum of the lengths of the intervals $I_n$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The length looks like $\sum_1^{\infty} 2^{1-n}$ which I think $1$, Is it correct? Then an open set of length $1$ can not be whole real line. Is this the argument correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s the argument, thoughthe sum is actually $2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes that was a typo. I corrected it. Thnx for your help.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Thnx a lot. Yes. The sum is $2$.